# Making rotating object draggable

Tags: javascript, processing

I'm new to Processing, and I'm attempting to manipulate my rectangle object so the user can drag the mouse to rotate it when the cursor is hovering over its position. However, I'm having trouble positioning a boundary box that both encompasses around my object and rotates correctly along with it. I've been trying a lot of different things attempting to get it to work but to no avail, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
float bx;
float by;
int boxSizeX = 150;
int boxSizeY = 30;
boolean overBox = false;
boolean locked = false;
float xOffset = 0.0; 
float yOffset = 0.0; 
float angle;

void setup()
{
  size(800, 600);
  frameRate(45);
  bx = width/2.0;
  by = height/2.0;
}

void draw()
{ 
  background(0);

  pushMatrix();
  translate(400, 425);
  rotate(angle);
  rect(-25, -15, boxSizeX, boxSizeY);
  popMatrix();

  rect(  bx-25, by-15,  boxSizeX, boxSizeY);
  //if (mouseX > bx-boxSizeX && mouseX < bx+boxSizeX && mouseY > by-boxSizeY && mouseY <     by+boxSizeY)
  if( mouseX > bx-25 && mouseX < bx+25+boxSizeX && mouseY > by-15 && mouseY < by+15+boxSizeY) {
    overBox = true;  
    if(!locked) { 
      stroke(255); 
      fill(153);
    } 
  } else {
    stroke(153);
    fill(153);
    overBox = false;
  }
}

void mousePressed() 
{
  if(overBox) { 
    locked = true; 
    fill(255, 255, 255);
  } else {
    locked = false;
  }
  xOffset = mouseX-bx; 
  yOffset = mouseY-by; 
}

void mouseDragged() 
{
  if(locked) {
     bx = mouseX-xOffset; 
     by = mouseY-yOffset; 
     angle = atan2(mouseY - 400, mouseX - 400);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. Basically, set a flag when you've clicked on the box. If the mouse is dragged AND the flag is true, then rotate.

```
int boxX, boxY;          // position of box
int boxRadius;           // width of box / 2
float boxAngle = 0.01;   // keep track of angle of rotation
boolean inBox = false;   // are we clicking in the box?

// have we clicked in the box?
void mousePressed() {
if (mouseX > boxX-boxRadius && mouseX < boxX+boxRadius && mouseY > boxY-boxRadius && mouseY < boxY+boxRadius) {
  inBox = true;
}

// stop behavior when we release the mouse
void mouseReleased() {
  inBox = false;
}

// rotate!
void mouseDragged() {
  if (inBox) {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(boxX, boxY);
    rotate(radians(boxAngle));
    fill(255,150,0);
    rect(0,0, boxRadius*2, boxRadius*2);
    popMatrix();

    // update the angle each frame
    boxAngle += 0.1;
  }
}
```